# print all files in folder and then remove them

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a web-based Point of Sale, and right now I am getting stuck with the VBScript.

The script should be printing all files in the selected folder, and after that I want to remove the files printed.
The selected folder will only contain PDF files that are going to be printed.

This is my current code:

```
TargetFolder = "C:\Users\pos\Downloads\"
If TargetFolder > "" Then
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder) 
  Set colItems = objFolder.Items
  For Each objItem in colItems
    objItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = fso.GetFile(TargetFolder+objItem)
    MyFile.Delete
  Next
Else
  Wscript.Quit
End If
```

All files are printed if I remove the remove file part, With the remove files it will delete all files before they get printed.

So what I want is to print the files, and remove them once they are printed.

Comment: Invoking the `Print` verb most likely runs asynchronously (call returns before putting the print job into the print queue completes), so I'd try doing the print jobs first, remove the files in a second loop, and put some delay between the loops to allow printing to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether printer jobs queue is empty before deleting files.

```
Do
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Document from Win32_PrintJob", , 48)
    WScript.Sleep(1000)
Loop While colItems.Count > 0
```

And then delete files in another loop.